# Url Rewrite from mysite.com/home/ to mysite.com/ in asp.net core

Tags: url, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

My rewrite rule in web.config properly redirects from "example.com/home" to "example.com/", but fails to redirect from "example.com/home/" (the only difference being the forward slash in the latter). I'd like to know how to get the second example to work. My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
          <rules>
               <rule name="mysite.com/home or mysite.com/home/ to mysite.com/" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)\/?\bhome\/?\b$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
               </rule>
          </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```